# Get value inside from a objects method in arraylist in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to select and get values from customer objects. What I want to do is to enter a personal number like "702312" and search after the customer objects that has a data member personal number that are equal to "702312". And when I found it I want to get the rest of the values or change it's content. This is some code that creates the customer objects from the class Customer and then it's stored in a arraylist.

```
// create a new customer object and send personal number, name and account number to constructor
Customer customer = new Customer(personalNumber, name, newAccountNumber);

// create an arraylist to store customer objects
ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();

// add the new customer object to arraylist that holds all customer objects
customerList.add(customer);
```

I have tried to reach the values like this, but it's not working, so I'm looking for some help?

```
 // search for customer
 for (Customer customer : customerList) {
if(customer.getAccountOwnerPersonalNumber() == "702312"){
    System.out.println("OK!!!");
    }
 }
```

And instead of:

```
 if(customer.getAccountOwnerPersonalNumber() == "702312")...
```

I have tried this:

```
 if(customer.personalNumber == "702312")...
```

Finally I have also tested it like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<customerList.size();i++){
    if(customerList.get(i).getAccountOwnerName() == "702312");
    System.out.println("OK");
    break;
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing right!? Help is preciated! Thanks!

Comment: what type returns .getAccountOwnerName() function? i think you are trying to compare number and string...

Comment: You are not calling the `System.out.println` method correctly.  Spaces must surround the parentheses like so:  `System.out.println ( "OK" ) ;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method to compare **objects** like `String`s by their internal value (otherwise they will only be compared by *reference*):

```
if (customer.getAccountOwnerPersonalNumber().equals("702312")) {
    System.out.println("OK!!!");
}
```

or, better, if it can potentially return `null`:

```
if ("702312".equals(customer.getAccountOwnerPersonalNumber())) {
    System.out.println("OK!!!");
}
```

or, if applicable, just make it a **primitive** like `int`, so that `==` will work the way you intended:

```
private int accountOwnerPersonalNumber;
```

with

```
if (customer.getAccountOwnerPersonalNumber() == 702312) {
    System.out.println("OK!!!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! With equals it worked fine! But how do I get the rest of the objects data member in the object that has personal Number equal "702312" ?

Comment: Just collect them in another `List` inside the loop. Ask a new question if you stucks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer and I'm stuck! Do you have time to show a bit of code?

Comment: Create a new `List<Customer>` before the loop, add the matching customers to that list inside the `if` block of the loop, exactly there where you've put the `System.out.println("OK!!!")`.

Comment: After some thinking, would it not be easier to do something like this: System.out.println(customerlist.get(i).getCustomerName(); to use the value of i as a index to the arraylist ??

Comment: Just choose whatever suits your functional requirement the best with most clean and self-documenting code.

Answer (score 1):

You want .equals():

```
if(customerList.get(i).getAccountOwnerName().equals("702312"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`customer.getAccountOwnerPersonalNumber() == "702312"` this is wrong you cant compare them like that because it will compare their object type. you should do like this

```
if(customer.getAccountOwnerPersonalNumber().equals("702312"))

or this is better

if("702312".equals(customer.getAccountOwnerPersonalNumber()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data that you query for is a String then in that case you have to use 
equals()

So the entire things will turn out to be

> if(customer.getAccountOwnerPersonalNumber().equals("702312")) {
>       System.out.println("OK!!!"); }

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare **customer.personalNumber** to **"702312"** which is a String, so i conclude  **customer.personalNumber** is a String too.
If I'm right, try **String.equals()** method instead of == operator. This is because this operator compares objects instead of value, which is what you want.

```
if(customer.getAccountOwnerPersonalNumber().equals("70312");)
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `java.util.Collections` `binarySearch(...)` method. It's of order O(log n)(in this case, since `ArrayList` implements `RandomAccess`) which is tons better than the O(n) order you get from doing your for loop.

You can make a separate comparator for the desired Customer fields(s)  (in this case "`personalNumber`"):

```
private static class CustomerPersonalNumberComparator implements Comparator<Customer> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
            return o1.getPersonaNumber().compareTo(o2.getPersonaNumber());
        }

    }
```

Also, don't forget to sort your list according to your desired search criteria (the Comparator) before using binary search on it:

```
Collections.sort(customerList,new CustomerPersonalNumberComparator());
int desiredIndex = Collections.binarySearch(customerList, new Customer("658",null,null), new CustomerPersonalNumberComparator());
Customer desiredCustomer = desiredIndex == -1 ?  null : customerList.get(desiredIndex);
```

And don't forget that the binary search returns the **position** inside our array for the desired element or -1 if nothing was found. So you must use that returned position to retrieve the desired instance from the list.